# Oracle Execute Immediate throws missing keyword error

Tags: oracle, plsql

In my stored procedure I use the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO COL_NO FROM user_tab_columns WHERE table_name='PAY_SLIP_FEB_16';
```

This query gives no error (because it shouldn't). But the table name here is fixed so I want to use a variable that will provide the table name. So I changed the query like this:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*) INTO COL_NO FROM user_tab_columns WHERE table_name='''||TBL_NAME||'''';
```

This query gives error:

```
ORA-00905: missing keyword
```

What did I do wrong? TIA.

N.B. : TBL_NAME is the incoming parameter that will provide the table name, and COL_NAME is just a NUMBER(5,0) type variable.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would expect the code to have the `INTO` as part of the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`, not in the dynamic query string:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_tab_columns WHERE table_name='''||TBL_NAME||''''
        INTO COL_NO ;
```

As a note:  I would write this using a separate variable:

```
v_sql  := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_tab_columns WHERE table_name = ''@TBL_NAME''';
v_sql := REPLACE(v_sql, '@TBL_NAME', TBL_NAME)

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql INTO v_COL_NO ;
```

Comment: what is the advantage of using `@TBL_NAME` and then replace it after?

Comment: @WahidMasud . . . I find it much easier to understand the query and to maintain it over time.  Concatenating a bunch of strings together makes it really hard to follow the logic in the subquery.